# url-rewriting htacces - how to rewrite my link?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have been looking all over the internet for this and found many clear documents on how to rewrite a url via htacces. I've gotten so far that htacces is working now, but my specific url(s) won't change. All kind of examples I have tried do not work. Hope someone here can help me with this.

This is my urL :

```
http://www.stamps-as-a-gift.com/category.php?cat1=Holland&cat2=Water&cat3=Vissen&cat4=Dolfijnen
```

No I would like it to been seen as:

```
http://www.stamps-as-a-gift.com/category/Holland/Water/Vissen/Dolfijnen
```

I like this because it is easier to remember en I have read it's also more SE friendly.

I hope this option is possible for me..thanks!

My code that isnt working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(cat1|cat2|cat3|cat4)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ category.php?cat=$1&cat2=$2&cat3=$3&cat4=$4
```

Also - do I need to restart apache after every new try ?

Comment: Can you show your attempted code (even if not working).

Comment: @anubhava I have edited my question so you can see my old code that is not working.

Comment: Do you have more rules or only this one?

Comment: @anubhava this is the only rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+category\.php\?cat1=([^\s&]+)&cat2=([^\s&]+)&cat3=([^\s&]+)&cat4=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ category/%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+category\.php\?cat1=([^\s&]+)&cat2=([^\s&]+)&cat3=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ category/%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+category\.php\?cat1=([^\s&]+)&cat2=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ category/%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+category\.php\?cat1=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ category/%1/? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?cat1=$1&cat2=$2&cat3=$3&cat4=$4 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?cat1=$1&cat2=$2&cat3=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?cat1=$1&cat2=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?cat1=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: great thank you! probably i am doing something wrong but for me it does not work. I know mod_rewrite is working because I have tried with a simple test ( click on link to oranges.php and get the content of apples.php )

Comment: yes example.com/category/Holland/Water/Vissen/Dolfijnen!

But if i start @ http://www.stamps-as-a-gift.com/start.php en i click trought the categories it does not work. Or is this normal ? The thing I wanted is when people click trought the categories the url changes directly. Is this even possible ? Stupid qeustion perhaps..thanks again

Comment: Sorry now I am not getting the question. Answer I provided is just for the URL structure you posted in question. This rule will make `example.com/category/Holland/Water/Vissen/Dolfijnen` work.

Comment: if you click on the link i provided you will see what i mean and trying to achieve ( if possible ) http://www.stamps-as-a-gift.com/start.php

Comment: looks like a code to bring someone to the moon and back! I have tried it - but if you click here: http://www.stamps-as-a-gift.com/start.php is does not work or am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65300/discussion-between-anubhava-and-bas-schreuder).